# Render image programmatically based on field content

Tags: theming, entities, 8

I am templating a resource page that has 5 different types of resources. I want to display a specific icon based on the type of resource. I want to do this programmatically so that later, users can upload a document, choose what type of resource it is, and the icon will automatically be displayed.

Now I'd like to be able to complete the logic of this inside the node--resource-asset.html.twig template using a for or if statement.

[image]
This is the kint display for the field_resource_type array. I want to generate the icon based on the markup string. This is what I've tried

```
{% for markup in content.field_resource_type %}
{% if markup == 'Datasheet' %}
<img class="icon" src="/img/icon_datasheet.png">
{% elseif markup == 'Whitesheet' %}
<img class="icon" src="/img/icon_whitepaper.png">
{% else %}
<img class="icon" src="/img/icon_casestudy.png">
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Nothing renders. Any suggestions on what I should be using as the key to call the correct part of the field?

Comment: This way the var `markup` will never get value 'Datasheet', Try `{% for markup in content.field_resource_type[0] %}`. This for statement is really necessary? Why you just try get content.field_resource_type[0]['#markup'] ?

Comment: You were right, I was just overthinking the problem. content.field_resource_type[0]['#markup'] worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have two primary things avaiable in a node template.

`content`: That contains rendered markup. Use it to print stuff.

`node`: This contains the node object with the raw values. Use this for comparisons and accessing the unformatted values. The same raw values would also be accessible through #items in content, but it's much more complicated to access.

So in your case, access the value with `node.field_resource_type.value`.

Note that this contains the key of the list field, and not the displayed label. I would recommend to always specify explicit keys (e.g., put datasheet|Datasheet in the allowed values field). Then you can also reliably translate those labels if you have a multilingual site and your template doesn't break.

Unless you actually have multiple values in there, you also don't need a loop. But if you do, you can loop over it with `for item in node.field_resource_type` and then use `item.value`.

See also http://wizzlern.nl/drupal/drupal-8-entity-cheat-sheet